# Subroutine with condition in batch file with cmake

Tags: batch-file

I write a batch file for making automate cmake and nmake, but i-ve a problem with conditional and subroutine inside. I want to send an email "if and only if" `levelerror`is not equal to 0. But when I asking that, he goes anyway to the subroutine.

I've put many `echo %errorlevel%` for debugging... but i can't find my error.

Here is my script :

```
cd C:\Users\name-user\Documents\Repos\corealpi\cmake\nmake
echo %errorlevel%

rm -R *
echo %errorlevel%

rmdir /q /s ..\..\build\cmake_x86d\
echo %errorlevel%

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
echo %errorlevel%

>"..\log\mailCmakeDeb.txt" cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G"NMake Makefiles" ..\
echo %errorlevel% 
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :mailcmaked      
echo %errorlevel%

>"..\log\buildDeb.log" nmake
echo %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :mailnmaked
echo %errorlevel%

pause

:mailcmaked
sendEmail -f from@mail.com -u "cmake failed" -t someone@mail.com -m "cmake debug failed" -a ..\log\mailCmakeDeb.txt -s 192.168.x.x
echo %errorlevel%
exit 1

:mailnmaked
grep -Eo '.{0,20}error.{0,100}' ..\log\buildDeb.log > ..\log\mailBuildDeb.txt
sendEmail -f from@mail.com -u "build debug/x86 failed" -t someone@mail.com -m "Nmake debug failed" -a ..\log\mailBuildDeb.txt -s 192.168.x.x
echo %errorlevel%
exit 1
```

I've always error = 0 but it still to go `:mailcmaked`...

Can you say me why ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested from where are your code entering `:mailcmaked`? As i see it, without anything failing, it will ALWAYS execute the code in the subroutine once the `pause` has been skipped.

Comment: If i removed the `pause` it still send an email... I search for a way he just send an email if cmake return error different than 0... but as you say he always execute the `:mailcmaked` section. And i don't understand why ?

Comment: Like @MCND said, you need an `exit` statement after the pause. `:mailcmaked` isn't a function, it's only a label

Comment: Ok, sorry @MCND i've not understand the first time. I add exit after pause and that's working great. Any stupid mistake of my part ^^ Thanks